# Merge the [anonymous] and [anonymous-visitors] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

[anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) and [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?